# How to identify that user has not deleted the app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have developed the Phonegap App.

I want to identify that app is installed in user mobile.

When user install app, h/she will register with our API server to use the app. First screen of APP is registration form.

We have maintained the UNIQUE user id so that we can identify the device and user.

I have used the push notification in APP.

Now I want to send the request to server from mobile that application is in mobile.

I want to code such that mobile will send the request to API server after specific interval of time. Time will be in days.

And the process to send request to server must run in background.

Can anyone help regarding this??

Comment: I think you want to use the native resources?? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, I want to use it. But to identify the app installed or not and if install send the request.

Answer (score 0):

If user deletes your app,how can you send request from mobile to your server? I think it'll be deleted with total instances so that there won't be any code with whom you can send request. If you found any way to send request after deletion, here is the code for checking if your application exists or not. It's native coede.

```
protected boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
        Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (mIntent != null) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

packageName is your app package name.

Comment: This is the native code. You need to search for a way to call native code from JS, or write a plugin to call native code. @user3305818